# How to properly handle data using asynchronous service with silverlight and telerik charts

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, asynchronous, telerik-charting

I have a silverlight application using telerik charts.

In my view I have the chart in xaml.  In the code behind of the view I have something like this:

```
public partial class MyView : UserControl
{
    private MyViewModel viewModel;

    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateChartMappings();  // Creates the SeriesMappings for my chart
        viewModel = new MyViewModel();
        Chart1.ItemsSource = viewModel.MyChartData;

        DataContext = viewModel;
        Resources.Add("ViewModel", viewModel);

    }
}
```

In my ViewModel I have this:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<ChartData> myChartData;
    public ObservableCollection<ChartData> MyChartData
    {
        get { return myChartData; }
        set { myChartData= value; OnPropertyChanged("MyChartData"); }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyWebServiceClient service = MyWebServiceClient.CreateInstance();

        service.GetChartDataCompleted +=  
            new EventHandler<GetChartDataCompletedEventArgs>(GetChartDataCallback); 

        service.GetChartDataAsync();
    }


    private void GetChartDataCallback(object sender, GetChartDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            MyChartData = e.Result;
        }
    }
}
```

I know for sure that GetChartData will return the correctly typed data that can be used for the chart and see that GetChartDataCallback does return results in e.Result, but I don't know how to get that data loaded into my chart.

If I do something like Chart1.ItemsSource = viewModel.MyChartData; after I am sure the service returns data then data loads into the chart fine.  For example, if I create a button in my view that calls that line of code it will load the data from the service into the chart.

Also if I replace the asyc calls with a normal method call it will work okay as well, so my problem might have something to do with not handling the asyc call correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two potential problems I see with the code you've presented above:

1. You're not binding the chart's ItemsSource to your view-model object.
2. There may be cross-thread issues depending on which thread handles the async callback.

When you assign to the `MyChartData` property in your `GetChartDataCallback` method, the PropertyChanged event is being fired.  But because you haven't bound anything in the view-layer to it, nothing is listening to this event.  Your chart will not get any new data.

To use binding, you can replace the line

```
Chart1.ItemsSource = viewModel.MyChartData;
```

with

```
Binding binding = new Binding("MyChartData") { Source = viewModel };
Chart1.SetBinding(RadChart.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

Alternatively, you could set up the binding in XAML.

As for the cross-thread issues, I don't have any code for an async service such as yours to test against.  Instead, I knocked up a simple test application that attempts to update the view-model data in a separate thread.  After making up some data, this application tries to assign this data to a view-model property much like yours above, using the line

```
ChartData = data;
```

When I ran this application, this line caused an UnauthorizedAccessException, which mentioned an invalid cross-thread access.

I replaced the line above with

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { ChartData = data; });
```

This change got rid of the exception and allowed me to see the (made-up) data in the chart.  (You'll need to add a line `using System.Windows;` if you don't already have one.)

Comment: You are correct about the binding.  Thank you.  I did have it in the XAML at one point, but had mispelled the binding name.  I didn't run into any issues with the service yet, but will keep your answer in mind if I do.